# Deleting node from single linked-list

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

One interviewer asked me the following question for "Single Linked List".

Q. In a single linked-list if we delete a node, then we need to re-link as below:

```
# deleting current_node say node 3
previous_node = node2
node3 = previous_node.next
next_node = node3.next
previous_node = next_node
```

So, here if we don't have the previous_node ( this is just a question from a interviewer ) how you will link the next node.

My Answer: In single linked list there is no option to traverse back, because the current_node doesn't have any information about the previous node. But he was not happy with my answer.

Could someone give me some light.

Thanks

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: How to linked the nodes from previous to next nodes after deleting. for example he deleted 3rd nodes, and he want to link 2nd and 4th, but he doesn't have 2nd node info.

Comment: He asked it in Python? What kind of deletion was used?

Answer (score 4):

Here is way to do it:-

1. Start for head and traverse till current->next == target
2. current->next = target->next
3. delete target

Comment: I think target is not available since it is deleted.

Comment: @VikramBhat didnt get u?

Comment: target has been deleted. Now we want to link its previous node to the earlier target->next node.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal How can you delete target without traversing the list? So why not update new pointer then.

Comment: I know but that's how the question is :)

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I would have slapped such a interviewer for asking such a idiotic question.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Has the interviewer placed null in place of previous's pointer( It is not mentioned ). In C you directly delete a node without erasing the pointer

Comment: Yes you r right. The question is ambiguous.

Comment: Releasing the memory for target before updating the link in the previous node is just not the right way to code a linked list removal. I think it is reasonable to assume target is still available, and only gets released after the code in this answer.

Comment: Sorry, if my question is confusing. Thats how i understood from the way he asked me, even i tried to clear out but he just repeat me the same.

Comment: @yopy Only thing u can do when someone asks such question is that it is not a logical and give him the explanation why and maybe he was expecting such an answer from u.

Comment: @vikram, Exactly thats what i m thinking right now, But i was not able to argue that while trying to figure out the answer :)

Comment: I know this question is really old but I had posted a detailed explanation on remove elements from linked lists in ruby at my blog https://medium.com/amiralles/mastering-data-structures-in-ruby-linked-lists-708347a30360

Answer (score 1):

Q. He deleted a node from a single linked list and he don't have the reference for the previous node, Is there a way to re-linked the previous node with the next.next nodes ?

What about if list is circular? Then, it is possible to re-link with O(n) complexity.

In your program

```
def go_backwards(node_ref):
    if node_ref == None:
        return
    head = node_ref
    _next = node_ref.next
    go_backward(_next)
    print head,
```

You are printing the list in reverse order, not actually reversing it.

```
def go_backwards(node_ref):
    head = node_ref
    _next = node_ref.next
    if _next == None:
        return node_ref 
    node = go_backward(_next)
    _next.next = head
    return node
```

Now, it will return reversed linked-list.

Comment: HI dbasic, he mentioned is a single linked list, thanks for the reversed code.

Comment: Then I hope that next of target node must be stored somewhere. Then answer of Vikram Bhat holds here.